# Load html com Jquery

Tags: jquery

Preciso chamar um **arquivo html e mostrar dentro de uma div**, utilizando o Jquery.

Tenho esse código jquery, que coloco o código html dentro da class **conteudo_abas**:

Como faria para chamar um arquivo html e mostrar dentra da class **conteudo_abas**?

```js
$('.abas').on('click', function(){
   $('.abas').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
   aba_index = $(this).attr('tabindex');

   this.aba1 = {
      conteudo: '<div class="conteudo_abas">dsad</div>'
   }

   this.aba2 = {
      conteudo: '<div class="conteudo_abas">asdsad</div>'
   }

   this.aba3 = {
      conteudo: '<div class="conteudo_abas">zxczx czxc zx</div>'
   }

   this.aba4 = {
      conteudo: '<div class="conteudo_abas">dffxg f</div>'
   }

   this.aba5 = {
      conteudo: '<div class="conteudo_abas"> sdfdsf </div>'
   }

  return $('#texto').html(this['aba' + aba_index]['conteudo']);
});

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.abas:first').trigger('click').addClass('active');
   
});
```

```css
.conteudo_abas{
  border:1px solid #000;  
}
.abas{
   display: inline-block;
   height: 40px;
   line-height: 40px;
   padding: 0 15px;
   text-align: center;
   border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
   float: left;
   cursor: pointer;
   outline: none;
}

.abas:hover,
.abas:focus{
   color: #fff;
}

.abas:nth-child(1){
   border-bottom-color: orange;
}
   .abas:nth-child(1):hover,
   .abas:nth-child(1):focus{
      background: orange;
   }

.abas:nth-child(2){
   border-bottom-color: red;
}
   .abas:nth-child(2):hover,
   .abas:nth-child(2).active {
      background: red;
   }

.abas:nth-child(3){
   border-bottom-color: purple;
}
   .abas:nth-child(3):hover,
   .abas:nth-child(3):focus{
      background: purple;
   }

.abas:nth-child(4){
   border-bottom-color: blue;
}
   .abas:nth-child(4):hover,
   .abas:nth-child(4):focus{
      background: blue;
   }

.abas:nth-child(5){
   border-bottom-color: green;
}
   .abas:nth-child(5):hover,
   .abas:nth-child(5):focus{
      background: green;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="margin-top:1000px;">
</div>
<div class="abas abas1" tabindex="1">
   Aba 1
</div>
<div class="abas abas2" tabindex="2">
   Aba 2
</div>
<div class="abas abas3" tabindex="3">
   Aba 3
</div>
<div class="abas abas4" tabindex="4">
   Aba 4
</div>
<div class="abas abas5" tabindex="5">
   Aba 5
</div>
<br clear="all" /><br />
<div id="texto"></div>
```

Comment: $("#divId").load("pagina.html")

Comment: é um sistema de abas e chamo os html assim, return $('#texto').html(this['aba' + aba_index]['conteudo']). Como faria para adaptar isso $("#divId").load("pagina.html")  ao meu código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe varias formas de trazer documentos via DOM para a pagina

`load() $.post() $.get()`
crie uma array com as paginas

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.abas').on('click', function(){
        var paginas = ["pagina1.html","pagina2.html","pagina3.html"];
        aba_index = $(this).attr('tabindex');
        $('.abas').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).load("caminho/"+paginas[parseInt(aba_index) - 1]);
    });
});
```

Comment: para cada aba seria uma página html diferente para se chamar, atualmente estou chamando assim, return $('#texto').html(this['aba' + aba_index]['conteudo']) como pode ver no código. Como faria isso com o seu código?

Comment: atualizei a resposta, crie uma array, e defina pela tab index o index da array a pagina

Comment: não consegui fazer funcionar, não está mostrando o arquivo html, vc poderia editar no JSFiddle?

Comment: verifica se o caminho  arquivo esté certo, aperta f12 e vai em  console e olha se está aparecendo algum erro, pos no jsfiddle eu n  consigo carregar arquivos dinamicamente

Comment: estranho não aparece nenhum erro no console e não abre o arquivo html, vc poderia fazer no jsfiddle? mesmo que nao de pra carregar arquivos dinamicamente. Só pra mim ver se estou fazendo certo. :)

Comment: Você não deve ter colocado dentro do $(document).ready(function(){ ... })

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/og06yxxj/

Comment: editei o codigo verifique agora

Comment: agora funcionou, só que tem o seguinte, quando clica em uma aba, o load() deve abrir o arquivo html  na <div id="texto"></div>, teria como?

Comment: sim, troque o $(this).load por $("#texto").load

Comment: se tiver resolvido o problema  não esqueça de marcar a respota como  correta

Comment: sim resolveu sim, obrigado ;)

Comment: como eu faria para colocar uma âncora, para que quando clica na aba, a barra de rolagem vai para div #texto?

Answer (score 0):

Você não precisa utilizar o jQuery para carregar o arquivo, na verdade. Apenas se você quiser, porque você pode simplesmente carregar o html em um `<object>` ou `<iframe>` inicialmente escondido e apenas mostra-lo depois.

Por exemplo, adicione no seu html em qualquer lugar:

```html
<object id=aba1 style='display: none' type="text/html" data="aba1.html"></object>
<object id=aba2 style='display: none' type="text/html" data="aba2.html"></object>
<object id=aba3 style='display: none' type="text/html" data="aba3.html"></object>
<object id=aba4 style='display: none' type="text/html" data="aba4.html"></object>
<object id=aba5 style='display: none' type="text/html" data="aba5.html"></object>
```

Posteriormente, você pode simplesmente jogar eles dentro do seu `.conteudo_abas` e mostra-los:

```
//Mostrei apenas a aba 01 mas você pode fazer igual pras outras.
$('.conteudo_abas').append($('#aba1'));
$('#aba1').show();
```

Ou se você não quiser gerar a `<div class=conteudo_abas>` via Javascript, seria mais facil ainda, você só precisaria deixar o seu html desta forma sem o uso de Javascript para nada:

```html
<div class=conteudo_abas>
  <object type="text/html" data="aba1.html"></object>
  <object type="text/html" data="aba2.html"></object>
  <object type="text/html" data="aba3.html"></object>
  <object type="text/html" data="aba4.html"></object>
  <object type="text/html" data="aba5.html"></object>
</div>
```

PS: `aba'X'.html` foi um nome de exemplo, renomeie para o nome do arquivo HTML desejado.